# Excel headers uneditable poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I want to make the header row of my excel uneditable using poi.

I got various solutions around the internet which say to firstly do `sheet.protectSheet("password")` which ultimately makes entire sheet uneditable and then loop through all cells which can be editable and set cellStyle for them as `cellStyle.setLocked(false)`.

In my case since the excel just contains headers and rest of the rows will be filled up by the user I can't make the entire sheet uneditable, I just want the headers to be uneditable by the user. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "i want just the headers to be uneditable by the user.": Then how would you fulfilling that requirement using `Excel`s GUI? Because `apache poi` cannot do something what `Excel` itself is not able to do.

Comment: @Fabien thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `XSSF` the following could be achieved:

Set a `CellStyle` having `setLocked` false as the default style for all columns. This is possible by setting a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCol` element having min col 1 and max col 16384 having set that style.

Then take out row 1 from using that style by setting `CustomFormat` true for that row. So it does not use the default style for all columns. Additional set a `CellStyle` having `setLocked` true as the default style for that row. This is possible by getting a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRow` element from that row and set `CustomFormat` and `S`(style) there.

Using current Apache POI versions new created cells in row 1 also need that  style as default row style not gets applied automatically.

Result: All cells are unlocked except row 1.

Example:

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelSheetProtectOnlyFirstRow {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  //create a CellStyle having setLocked false
  CellStyle cellstyleUnprotect = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellstyleUnprotect.setLocked(false);
  //create a CellStyle having setLocked true
  CellStyle cellstyleProtect = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellstyleProtect.setLocked(true);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  //set the CellStyle having setLocked false as the default style for all columns
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCol cTCol = 
      ((XSSFSheet)sheet).getCTWorksheet().getColsArray(0).addNewCol();
  cTCol.setMin(1);
  cTCol.setMax(16384);
  cTCol.setWidth(12.7109375);
  cTCol.setStyle(cellstyleUnprotect.getIndex());

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

  //set CustomFormat true for that row
  //so it does not using the default style for all columns
  //and set the CellStyle having setLocked true as the default style for that row
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRow cTRow = 
      ((XSSFRow)row).getCTRow();
  cTRow.setCustomFormat(true);
  cTRow.setS(cellstyleProtect.getIndex());

  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
   Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
   cell.setCellValue("Header " + (c+1));
   cell.setCellStyle(cellstyleProtect);
  }

  sheet.protectSheet("password");   // protect sheet

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelSheetProtectOnlyFirstRow.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```